# Tomcat 8.5.6 is giving "403 Access Denied" Error in cent OS 7

Tags: tomcat, centos, tomcat8

I am getting the problem given by $subject when I am trying to access through an external browser. I have changed context.html in ../manager/META-INFO/context.html. The content looks like follows.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="^.*S" />
</Context>
```

In addition, I have allowed port 8080 for tcp in firewall. What could be the possible solution?

Thanks in Adavance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by editing:

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/manager/context.xml

${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/host-manager/context.xml

${CATALINA_HOME}/config/context.xml
```

To allow access only for the clients connecting from localhost:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
 allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/>
```

To allow unrestricted access for the clients connecting from localhost but for all other clients only to port 8443:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
  addConnectorPort="true"
  allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+;\d*|::1;\d*|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;\d*|.*;8443"/>
```

To allow unrestricted access to port 8009, but trigger basic authentication if the application is accessed on another port:

```
<Context>
  ...
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         addConnectorPort="true"
         invalidAuthenticationWhenDeny="true"
         allow=".*;8009"/>
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"/>
  ...
```

And tomcat-users.xml in ${CATALINA_HOME}/config

```
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="user" password="secret" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```